# how to seperate the files according to album in mp3

Tags: c#

i am doing a mediaplayer project and in that i need some help

i added all the *.mp3 files to a list box and now i want to separate the files according to the album names..
i know how to gain album name

```
string songTitle = tagFile.Tag.Title;
string artist = tagFile.Tag.AlbumArtists.FirstOrDefault();
string albumTitle = tagFile.Tag.Album;
uint year = tagFile.Tag.Year;
string genre = tagFile.Tag.Genres.FirstOrDefault();
```

but how to group them by same name
and if possible how to get the image of the file also..

do we have to use some search method for this..?

please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list is of the above tagFiles, Use linq like so :

```
SongList.GroupBy(t => t.Tag.Album);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shahar regarding grouping.
For picture, I have used following code:

```
IPicture newArt = new Picture(tmpImg);
tagFile.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[1] {newArt};
tagFile.Save();

var file = TagLib.File.Create(filename);
if (file.Tag.Pictures.Length >= 1)
{
    var bin = (byte[])(file.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
    PreviewPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin)).GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: this is helpful to get the imaged thumbnail